odin programming language: vulkan.CreateDevice() crashes program on execution
I am useing vulkan with the odin programming language. My program is crashing after attempting to call the procedure vulkan.CreateDevice() (fyi procedures are just functions in odin).
My code for creating the device looks like this:
bonbug.actionStart("Creating Device");
    vulkan.load_proc_addresses(get_proc_address);
    queuePriority : f32 = 1.0;
    dQCreateInfo : []vulkan.DeviceQueueCreateInfo = {{
        sType = .DEVICE_QUEUE_CREATE_INFO,
        queueFamilyIndex = deviceIndex,
        queueCount = 1,
        pQueuePriorities = &queuePriority,
    }};
    deviceFeatures : vulkan.PhysicalDeviceFeatures;
    dCreateInfo : vulkan.DeviceCreateInfo = {
        sType = .DEVICE_CREATE_INFO,
        pQueueCreateInfos = raw_data(dQCreateInfo),
        queueCreateInfoCount = cast(u32)len(dQCreateInfo),
        pEnabledFeatures = &deviceFeatures,
        enabledExtensionCount = 0,
        enabledLayerCount = layerCount,
        ppEnabledLayerNames = cast([^]cstring)raw_data(requestedLayers),
    };

        fmt.printf("test");
    vulkan.CreateDevice(devices[deviceIndex], &dCreateInfo, nil, &device);
bonbug.actionEnd();

Bonbug is just a debugging package. My program is called bonfire so that's how I came up with the name.
Vulkan does not show any error message. I know that the program crashes when running vulkan.CreateDevice() because the printf("test") goes through.
The resulting output is this:
BONBUGGER: Creating Device... test

Notice that there is no "DONE" at the end of that line (thats what bonbug.actionEnd() does), this verifies that the program has crashed.
This behavior has happened before with another vulkan procedure. I fixed with this bit of code:
context.user_ptr = &instance;
get_proc_address :: proc(p: rawptr, name: cstring) 
{
    (cast(^rawptr)p)^ = glfw.GetInstanceProcAddress((^vulkan.Instance)(context.user_ptr)^, name);
}

vulkan.load_proc_addresses(get_proc_address);

That worked for that procedure; however I tried running "vulkan.load_proc_addresses(get_proc_address);" again before the CreateDevice() procedure, but it did not work.
Please help as I have not found any vulkan documentation for odin, but I am too far into the project to convert it to c++.

What is the value of dCreateInfo.pNext before calling CreateDevice? What exception is being thrown during the crash?

@vandench There is no value for pNext but the tutorial does not say I need one. There is no exception being thrown which is why i'm confused.

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer to this question or not but I have been working on this problem and thought I'd share what I've discovered with others.
The Vulkan library when imported is "incomplete" in a sense. All the methods/functions we need to use Vulkan exist but as templates not as real functions. In order to use the functions we have to tell the library where to find the functions first.
We can do this using the overloaded function:
vulkan.load_proc_addresses()
. This function is overloaded with the following 5 functions:

load_proc_addresses_global(vk_get_instance_proc_addr: rawptr)
load_proc_addresses_instance(instance: Instance)
load_proc_addresses_device(device: Device)
load_proc_addresses_device_vtable(device: Device, vtable: ^Device_VTable)
load_proc_addresses_custom(set_proc_address: SetProcAddressType)


load_proc_addresses_global(vk_get_instance_proc_addr: rawptr):
This function takes a pointer to a function as an argument and is used to get access to the most basic of Vulkan functions required to create the Vulkan instance.

load_proc_addresses_instance(instance: Instance):
By passing a vulkan.Instance to this function we can get access to the next level of Vulkan functionality required to create a physical and logical device.

load_proc_addresses_device(device: Device)
After passing a vulkan.Device to this function we have completed all the function definitions and can use the complete Vulkan functionality.

With this we can put together a basic Vulkan init method:
import "vendor:glfw"
import vk "vendor:vulkan"

initVulkan :: proc() {
    // load_proc_addresses_global :: proc(vk_get_instance_proc_addr: rawptr)
    vk.load_proc_addresses((rawptr)(glfw.GetInstanceProcAddress));

    instance : vk.Instance = createVkInstance();
    
    // load_proc_addresses_instance :: proc(instance: Instance)
    vk.load_proc_addresses(instance)

    physicalDevice : vk.PhysicalDevice = pickPhysicalDevice()
    device : vk.Device = createLogicalDevice(physicalDevice)
    
    // load_proc_addresses_device :: proc(device: Device)
    vk.load_proc_addresses(device)
}

And that's it. With this (assuming you make the instance and devices correctly) the Vulkan library is fully functional.

But what of the last two functions I hear you ask:

load_proc_addresses_device_vtable(device: Device, vtable: ^Device_VTable)
load_proc_addresses_custom(set_proc_address: SetProcAddressType)

Well we don't need them. From what I can tell load_proc_addresses_device_vtable is only used if you plan to use multiple devices at once. This is because each device will have their own function locations associated with them requiring the programmer to store the correct function locations for each device.
load_proc_addresses_custom on the other hand takes a function pointer and maps all of Vulkans functions using it. I can't think of any sane reason you would wish to do this yourself so don't go near this unless you really know what you're doing.

This was exactly what i was looking for. Was thinking why i cant run a simple Vulkan program on Odin...
